# Why Cant I Right Click And Run A JPanel Form Inside A Package On Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jpanel

so i'm a beginner to code on Java for my Project on Netbeans. On my project i've created a Java Package, and inside that Package i created a JPanel Form for the GUI, however when i try to right click the JPanel, the "Run File" button is grayed out, what is the issue?

(i can run from a Java Class)

Below is the code generated from the JPanel Form, with little of modifications :

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JPanel.java to edit this template
 */
package GUI;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author rizkiaswangga
 */
public class Menu2 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu2
     */
    public Menu2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jTextField1.setText("Welcome To Our Game Store !");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setText("You Can Browse Your Game Here");
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255));
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 51));
        jButton1.setText("Browse Games");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField2)
                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(137, 137, 137))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // Go To Browse Games :
        JFrame Browse = new JFrame();
        Browse.show();
        
        dispose();
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

N.B. i've used Apache Netbeans 16 on Arch Linux downloaded from repo, and i created Java with Maven

i've tried to make a new project, restarting Netbeans, and still, running the file from JPanel doesn't work

Comment: cause your class does not have main method so create main method and create JFrame instance and setit contentpane with an instance of that jpanel

Comment: Thanks for the info, i just create JFrame instead of JPanel and it works flawlessly...

Comment: you welcome check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html to know more about top level container and why you needed jframe to run your program as jpanel is not top level